# Would A Gravity Blade Be Possible To Create?

Tags: technology, weapons, gravity, artificial-gravity

I am wanting to use gravity based weaponry in my plot.  One of my ideas was to have some sort of blade that could focus extreme gravitational forces at the edge of the blade to slice through matter (essentially ripping it apart).  The gravity would be artificially induced by some means.  Assuming the power production technology exists, would this be doable?

The forces would propagate from either side of the blade, and converge at the edge.  At least, that’s my original idea.

Also, a gravity blade should be able to parry another gravity blade.  Special armor that can produce a gravitational shield may also exist.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better served by starting by saying "In my world there are gravity blades which can parry each other." than trying to justify such a cool idea in the mundane realm of what is possible in the real world.

Comment: Isn't gravity by definition an *attractive* force? Gravity weapons and armour would actually pull swinging enemy weapons *towards* you, wouldn't they?

Comment: Perhaps gravity/anti-gravity?

Comment: the problem is if the gravity is high enough to warp space it is high enough a human can't swing it, gravity is gravity it does not matter if it comes from mass or not.

Comment: @John, so would an anti-gravitational force avoid that problem?

Comment: I don't think you grasp how gravity works, gravity is fairly weak force, but a sword with negative gravity strong enough to effect something else would explode is it would be being pulled apart by as much force as it can exert on anything it "cuts" It might also have negative inertia which might make it completely useless as a weapon.

Comment: Then maybe artificially produced little black holes produced at the edge of the blade?  I’m hoping to avoid using laser or plasma for my weapons, I was hoping to use something a bit more original.  Is there some other force that could get me a similar effect?  Thanks for the feedback. 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we help you create and consistently use the rules of a fictional world of your own creation. Asking if a fictional technology you want in your fictional world can be built in the real world is off-topic. Asking for help developing and explaining your fictional technology is on topic - but that requires you to rewrite your Q and be specific about the help you need (we won't design the whole thing for you).

Comment: I think you need two "impossible" technologies here.  One to make gravity without mass, and one to compress the gravitational field so that it's intense enough to do serious damage near the edge, but drops off to near zero a short distance from the blade.  Tiny black holes in sci-fi sometimes sometimes seem to have compressed fields like this, so they can exist in a room without attracting any furniture but still drill a hole through the floor when dropped.  Maybe you could handwave the highly compressed field as an extension of the research that led to artificial gravity for small spaceships.

Comment: "_I’m hoping to avoid using laser or plasma for my weapons, I was hoping to use something a bit more original_". Just make something up, or handwave something in. "Warp"-whatever is a classic. The less you associate your concept with real physics, the less scope there is for you being unambiguously wrong. Just don't go into detail... you want magic swords, you've got em. hack away.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback!  I will probably just have to assume it is some different force producing the ripping force, and avoid going into detail as has been recommended.

Comment: Or go with the compressed field black hole idea.

Comment: One interesting thing about the compressed field idea as an extension of ship gravity, is that artificial gravity harnessing is one of the largest defining technologies of this civilization.  They have developed gravity generators for their ships, and for the planets they terraform.  I’m thinking they have also harnessed traversable wormholes for “FTL” travel.  So a highly compressed field would make some semblance of sense, though with all of these technologies, I should probably be pretty vague in describing how they work.

Comment: What exactly about these things makes them a **gravity** blade, besides the name of course?

Comment: I originally was thinking that a powerful gravitational field focused at the edge in such a way that it would rip apart objects when it passed through them, basically splitting or slicing objects that didn’t have a gravity shield that could counteract the field of the blade.  I may still go that route if I can, perhaps with the graviton explanation.  This civilization has constructed gravity generators for the terraformed planets they’ve inhabited and their ships.  They may even use this technology to produce traversable wormholes to travel across vast distances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of one thing: A sword made of gravitons.

It sounds awesome, let's be honest. Plus, there is plenty of science to back it up. Gravitons are the (theoretical) quantum form of gravity. Based on some facts we know about gravity, we've deduced that its properties. It must be neutrally charged, since empty space has no charge. And, more importantly in our case, since gravity has infinite range, it must have exactly 0 mass! So, if you get a crapton of these guys into a sword, you've got your deal.

Problems: As Don Lincoln of Fermilab puts it, "At the moment, gravitons are entirely theoretical constructs that delicately walk the knife-edge precipice between the domains of scientific respectability and the shady world of hand waving. ... [They] are a theoretically reputable idea, but are not proven."

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  That sounds like it might possibly work! 

Comment: @KalMadda Here's a link to the website I used for this, if it helps: https://news.fnal.gov/2012/10/gravitons/

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! 

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

To the best of our knowledge (with the proviso that we could in fact be wrong about this) gravity is the result of motion through curved spacetime. Also as far as we know the only thing that changes the curvature of spacetime is the presence of mass. You'd need an edge on the blade that weighed several million tons to produce the sort of effect you're looking for, which makes it unlikely that you'll be able to do anything to move the damned thing.

There could be other ways to warp space, using some sort of obscure field effect. The energy requirements would be ruinous, not to mention that the size of the energy storage would be sufficient to make your sword useless as a weapon. At a bare minimum you'd have to provide as much energy as it takes to tear the object apart, and that's assuming you only activate it as necessary.

And no, as far as we know there's no such thing as "anti-gravity". You'd have to produce a *negative* curvature on space, which quite possibly doesn't even make sense. Even if we accept that there is some sort of field effect that could manipulate the curvature of space, it would still be ruinously expensive to counter the existing curvature caused by other parts of the system.

Now if you're happy to depart from actual science, there are plenty of options. As long as you're looking for a realism-adjacent option then you're out of luck.

Simpler to just use a chainsword, either way.

Comment: Chainswords aren't _quite_ the silliest melee weapon idea out there, but they're not far off. There's nothing good about them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 

Comment: Negative curvature is certainly a thing. It just means the sum of the angles of a very small triangle is less than 180. [In 2D it looks like this.](https://cqgplus.files.wordpress.com/2018/11/topological-bhs-2.png?w=609&h=352)

Comment: It wouldn't produce negative mass though.

Comment: @Daron The saddle curvature is interesting and satisfies the triangle specification, but only in specific parts. Outside the focus of the saddle you can draw many 180+ triangles. It can be done in 3D space, since curvature is more to do with circumference/diameter. Positive curvature decreases π, negative curvature increases it. Or something. It's all very hard to visualize.

Comment: @Corey I think the saddle has negative curvature at every point and not just the focus.

Comment: @Daron You could be right, assuming there is a pinch effect - possibly  parabolic or *maybe* hyperbolic - towards the saddle focus on both axes. But it seems that once you isolate the triangle to one of the 'wings' of the saddle you're in an area that looks a lot like positive curvature.